# Difference betwwen processing 1,400,000 orders per second and 1,400,000 concurrent connections

Tags: performance, connection, performance-testing, load-testing, binance

You may have heard that some cryptocurrency exchange platforms claim to be able to proceed 1,400,000 orders per second. My question is that is this the same as having 1,400,000 concurrent connections per second?

Please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily, in the majority of cases the number of connections will be higher.

I would say that 1.4M orders per second can stand for 1.4M connections only if the system is being used by i.e. [trading bots](https://bravenewcoin.com/news/cryptocurrency-trading-bots/) which are capable of placing an order in a single request.

If the system is being used by a "normal" human using a web browser the number of connections will be approx. 5 times higher mostly due to [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) requests. In case of [real browsers](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) you will also need to think about cookies, cache, embedded resources and so on.

So in order to come up with a well-behaved load test you need to identify [how exactly the system will be used](http://www.agileload.com/agileload/blog/2013/06/12/performance-test-workload-modeling) and design your test plan to simulate this real usage as close as possible, otherwise the load test will not make a lot of sense.

Comment: The system is being used by humans using web browsers. So the number of connections here is about 5 times higher than 1.4M. This is quite a big number.